# How to pass a dynamcally allocated array into a function in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, pass-by-reference

I am very fresh with Excel VBA, so I ask you for understanding. Doing research on the internet has not resolved my problem. So I wish to pass an array of numerical values in VBA into a function, namely enter cash flows into an NPV function all in Excel VBA code.

```
Dim Postavke() As String, velikost As Integer, i As Integer

velikost = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("List1").Columns(11))

ReDim Postavke(velikost)

For i = 1 To velikost
    Postavke(i) = Cells(i + 1, 11).Value
Next i
```

Now I want to pass the `Postavke()` array to the NPV function:

```
Dim NSV As Long

NSV = NPV(0.06, ByRef Postavke() As Long))
```

which always goes an error. Any thoughts to how this might be done?

Thank you in advance. Best regards.

Comment: You defined `Postavke` as a `String` array.

Comment: Note too that your array will be zero-based by default.

Answer (score 1):

Create the function in this way:

```
Function NPV(whatever As Double, Postavke() As String) As Long
    Dim x As Long
    'do whatever you want with your code, work on the 'x' variable and finally ends with:
    NPV = x
    'or define NPV earier and use Exit Function after..
End Function
```

You must decide if the Postavke() array must be declared as a string or a long. I kept your initial declaration...

And call the function like this:

```
NSV = NPV(0.06, Postavke())
```

In order to properly load velikost, starting with 1, you must add on top of your module code:

```
Option Base 1
```

Otherwise, you must take care (like @SJR remarked) that the array is zero-based by default.